# How does a processor inform a device unit that its interrupt request has been recognized in interrupt driven I/O?

Tags: io, hardware

In this book I'm reading: *Computer Organization and Embedded Systems*, there's this paragraph that I don't quite understand:

> We should note that as part of handling interrupts, the processor must inform the device that its request has been recognized so that it may remove its interrupt-request signal. This can be accomplished by means of a special control signal, called interrupt acknowledge, which is sent to the device through the interconnection network. An alternative is to have the transfer of data between the processor and the I/O device interface accomplish the same purpose. The execution of an instruction in the interrupt-service routine that accesses the status or data register in the device interface implicitly informs the device that its interrupt request has been recognized.

I understand the interrupt acknowledge concept, but I'm having trouble understanding the last two sentences in the paragraph. What do they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two sentences mean that the processor may not send any special control signal to acknowledge the devices, instead the processor can execution something (such as get device register information or get sensor data), when the devices received those normal instruction, mean that the CPU is running and finished working for the interrupt, the devices will remove its interrupt-request signal (cancel interrupt), run as normal and process the requirement (such as read and send back sensor reading) from processor.

Comment: I see, thank you! You said that when the device receives some sort of instruction (e.g. when the processor access the device register information), it will remove its interrupt-request. How does the device do this? I suppose there's some sort of bit to do so?

Comment: It depending on protocol between host and device, such as some sensor will auto resume from interrupt mode if any enquire happen, the interrupt bit staus will changed automatically .

Comment: I see, thank you! Do you have a link that provides a more in-depth description to your comment? I'm intrigued in the intricate process of one of the ways the device can do that.

Comment: You may reference of this link https://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/beginner-s-corner/4023338/Introduction-to-Interrupts                                                           In most cases, a specific ISR is responsible for servicing each interrupting device and acknowledging, clearing, and rearming its interrupt; in some cases, servicing the device (for example, reading data from a serial port) automatically clears and rearms the interrupt.